# Google map navigation option for ios

Tags: ios, dictionary

How I show built in navigation options on google map iOS source and destination and navigation with voice or I have to implement google map api for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code; it'll appear the selected location with drop annotation; and from google app you can navigate

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme

```
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]])
 {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?center=%f,%f&q=%f,%f",mosqueLocation.latitude,mosqueLocation.longitude, mosqueLocation.latitude,mosqueLocation.longitude]];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else {
  NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```